# MongoDB with Powershell

Tags: json, mongodb, powershell

I'm retriving a VM utilization details in a variable($report)which is in JSON format.

$report looks something like:

```
{
   { 
   "VM_Name" : "VMtest1"
   "Datastore":"KJo91"
   },
   { 
   "VM_Name" : "VMtest2"
   "Datastore":"KJo91"
   },so on....
}
```

Now I need to import this into MongoDB via powershell.
Is it possible?Or should I save it as a Jsonfile and import?
For both cases required a powershell command.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You need to use Mongo C# driver and then the standard .NET object approach. Check this links: [C# and .NET MongoDB Driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) and [Using Mongodb with PowerShell](https://reszolver.wordpress.com/2017/01/03/using-mongodb-with-powershell/)

Comment: Yes I have used C# MongoDB Driver.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have used C# MongoDB Driver, I can import a JSON file (`Sample1.json`) into MongoDB, e.g.

```
# Command Used
$report = Get-VM #retrives the VM Details
$report | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1 | Out-File "Path" # Here a file is saved in the specified path and I can import the file to MongoDB using the below command:
.\mongoimport.exe  --db $dbName --collection $collectionName ./sample1.json --jsonArray
```

Instead of creating a file, I'm using a variable which has the data in JSON format:

```
# Command used
$result = $report | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1
```

Now I have to import the `$result` variable (which contains the collection/document) into MongoDB.